# git bash: why does bash on Windows start a new instance of itself in order to run an external command?

Tags: bash, git-bash

If you start git-bash and monitor bash.exe with procmon, you will see that just running a simple command like clear starts a new instance of `bash.exe`. This instance doesn't stick around for the lifetime of the external command - it is started and almost immediately terminates. Thus if you type `grep hello` you will see that although the `grep` process is still running the additional `bash.exe` process terminates.

Is there a reason bash launches a new `bash.exe` process and is there any way to change this behaviour? It causes performance problems in certain environments were antivirus software is checking every process that starts: one more process is another half-second delay.

Comment: In Unix, the standard way of starting a new process is to fork the current one, leaving you momentarily with two process with identical state, then exec-ing the new program in the child process. The second `bash` probably isn't *terminating*, but rather *becoming* `grep`. (I don't know how or if that translates into the Windows program.)

Comment: (Possibly some sort of Windows-specific "simulation" of `fork` so that `bash` itself can be executed with a minimal number of Windows-specific patches to its own source code?)

Comment: Thanks. I agree that this is probably a simulation of `fork` - however, a process cannot exactly "become" another process in Windows as far as I know and procmon confirms this: the additional `bash.exe` terminates after `grep.exe` starts. So this is a "pseudo-becoming" :)